# Under Linux, is there any language that offers lower latency than C? (apart from assembler)

Tags: linux, low-latency

I've been looking at various languages (mostly functional) that offer some great potential for throughput and concurrency. However, for latency sensitive applications (by which I mean the potential to respond to an event < 1ms) seems to be beyond them.

I can do this in C, but I was wondering if anything had come along offering low latency and high concurrency, or are they (as I suspect) mutually exclusive?

Note: In a previous question there was a lot of discussion over the "mutually exclusive" bit - but I think it stands - if you need extremely low latency, you cannot get massive concurrency. I would absolutely love to be proven wrong on this! :-)

Comment: That depends on what kind of system... you could mirror your system once for each user and sync them later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between C and asm is unlikely to be a major factor in response latency. After all, before reaching your code, the system will have to run a fair bit of C code in the Linux kernel first, in order to schedule in your process. You'd be better off doing things like turning on threaded interrupt handlers, setting real-time priorities, and disabling BIOS features that may cause system-management-mode traps.

Comment: +1 latency comes from user-mode scheduling, not from the programming language.  Using kernel-mode handlers is the surest way to cut latency.

Comment: +1 ... and even user-mode scheduling works _very well_ below 1ms on my standard, totally non-impressive Ubuntu Desktop box. I've once timed a million 10-microsecond waits on a `timerfd`, taking very slightly more (a dozen ms) than 10 seconds alltogether. That shows that both timer resolution and accurracy as well as latency are perfectly ok for anything remotely reasonable. Of course, if you want to handle events in the nanosecond range, you'll have a problem...

Comment: If you're in a blocked thread for example, and an event occurs, it can take more than 1ms for the thread to be notified depending on what the system is doing. Besides 1ms is the maximum delay - I would prefer latency < 100us.

Comment: But my question still stands - can any language other than C, provide the same low latency that is possible with C? Erlang and Java for example cannot.

Comment: @PeterM, fortran could probably do it ;)

Comment: @PeterM You can have < 1 ms latency in Java two ways.  You can use Azul's Zing which has concurrent collection or reduce the garbage you are producing assuming you can perform a cleanup once a day or once a week (which not trading).  Using this approach you can have a typical delay of 60 micro-seconds external to the box for a real tick to trade trading system with a worst case latency below 1 ms (while trading)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by latency? C is not much more than portable assembler. Most C instructions are directly mapped to processor instructions. C overhead is very minimal, compared to other languages. If you mean latency as in DSP programming, you probably need to check input and output times, not processing itself.

Comment: But C also has overhead for function calls and the like, that cannot always be optimized away.

Answer (score -1):

[Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) seems to be the language that the big guns use for stuff like this.

Comment: Erlang is _not_ a hard real time system. GC delays can easily exceed 1ms.